# Capturing one of many args in a python __init__

Tags: python

If I have a class like this:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    print a, b, c, d
```

and a derived class like this:

```
class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "c" in kwargs:
            kwargs['c'] = 'else'  # CHANGE C IFF IT IS PRESENT
        super(bar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

when someone calls this constructor, they could do it like this:

```
bar('a','b','c','d')
```

or they could call it like this:

```
bar('a', c='something')
```

In the second case, my constructor works as planned, but in the case of the first call `c` sneaks thru in the args array.  This looks like I would have to watch the length of the args array as well as kwargs, and that seems brittle to the point of unusable.  Is there anything you can do to make this situation better, other than just enumerate the arguments from foo in bar?  (A somewhat brittle practice itself, but easier to recognize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more brittle than you think. Have you considered the situation where someone passes a keyword argument not present in `foo.__init__`'s argument list (e.g. `bar('a', f='something')`)? My recommendation would be requiring `bar` to take keyword arguments only and then filter the keys not present in `foo.__init__`'s argument list (which you can determine via introspection using [`inspect.getargspec`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) [or related functions for newer versions of Python, particularly the `Signature` and `Parameter` objects starting in 3.3] if the arguments may change). That in itself has its own form of brittleness, of course, as a programmer using `bar` would need to know the relevant argument names for `foo`'s constructor, but depending on what `bar` is being used for they may need to know what arguments `foo` takes anyway, and when someone knows that they usually know what the names of the arguments are as well.

Now that I'm looking at `inspect` again, I realize that there's another method you could use: [`inspect.getcallargs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs), which might be more useful for you. With this, you could do, say, `inspect.getcallargs(super(bar, self).__init__, *[self, 1], **{'c':3, 'd':4})` and obtain the following dict: `{'a': 1, 'self': <bar object>, 'b': None, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}`. Then you can modify that dictionary and supply it as `super(bar, self).__init__(**fixed_dict)` or something of that sort. You'd still have the issue with keyword arguments not present in `foo.__init__`'s argument list, though (`getcallargs` raises the same errors `foo.__init__` will when passed invalid arguments).

Answer (score 2):

How about populating `kwargs` with `args`?

```
class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for name, value in zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], args): # <---
            kwargs[name] = value                            # <---
        args = ()                                           # <---
        if "c" in kwargs:
            kwargs['c'] = 'else'
        super(bar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**UPDATE**

Alternative that use [`inspect.getcallargs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getcallargs):

```
import inspect

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = inspect.getcallargs(foo.__init__, self, *args, **kwargs)
        kwargs.pop('self')
        if 'c' in kwargs:
            kwargs['c'] = 'else'
        super(bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Part of the problem with this is I'm still required to know the names and order of the parameters, and if that base class isn't under your control, it could change.  I could as easily enumerate the named parameters in `__init__` to match those of the base class and then I don't need zip, but if that order changes, (that's the brittleness I'm speaking of).

Comment: @Mark0978, You can use `inspect.getargspec(foo.__init__).args[1:]` in place of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

Comment: @Mark0978, As JAB answered, you can also use `inspect.getcallargs`. See http://ideone.com/EjD1r8

Comment: Yea, that's why I put the comment on this answer instead of JAB's.